# Adding new Debezium Connector to Apache Kafka restarts snapshot

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using debezium/Kafka(v1.0) that uses Apache Kafka 2.4.

In addition, I have deployed a debezium mysql connector that monitor some tables configured to take snapshot at beginning, at this point is all good.

After a time I have the need to start monitoring other tables, so I create another connector, this time without snapshot because is not needed.

This produces that the first connector start to take the snapshot again.

Is this an expected behavior?

How is the procedure to start monitoring new tables without the others connector take the snapshot again?

thanks in advance.

**EDIT configs added:**

*First Connector*

```
{
  "name": "orion_connector_con_snapshot_prod_v1",
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "database.hostname": "my_host",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "database.user": "my_db",
  "database.password": "*********************",
  "database.server.name": "orion_kafka",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "history_orion",
  "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
  "database.history.store.only.monitored.tables.ddl": "true",
  "table.whitelist": "my_db.my_table_1,my_db.my_table_2,my_db.my_table_3",
  "snapshot.mode": "when_needed",
  "snapshot.locking.mode": "none"
}
```

*The second connector that start the problem*

```
{
  "name": "nexo_impactos_connector_sin_snapshot_v1",
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "database.hostname": "my_host",
  "database.port": "3306",
  "database.user": "my_db",
  "database.password": "*********************",
  "database.server.name": "nexo_kafka",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "nexo_impactos",
  "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
  "database.history.store.only.monitored.tables.ddl": "true",
  "table.whitelist": "other_db.other_table",
  "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
  "snapshot.locking.mode": "none"
}
```

Comment: Does the first connector *finish* its snapshot before you add the second connector? Or is it still taking the snapshot? You can see this in the worker log.

Comment: Hi thansk for answer! yes, it´s finish several weeks ago, and all have been working great, today when i add the second connector I saw in my logs the first connector starting the snapshot again.

Comment: Please show all relevant configs

Comment: Configs added to the question